# Inverse of Symmetric Matrix Plus Diagonal Matrix if Square Matrix's Inverse Is Known

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ symmetric matrix of rank $n$ with known inverse $A^{-1}$.  Let $D$ be a diagonal matrix with the same dimensions and rank.  What is the fastest way to compute $(A+D)^{-1}$?  Assume all diagonal elements of $A+D$ are positive and that $A+D$ is invertible.

Comment: Is there a difference between the two phrases: "$A+D$ possess all the qualities necessary to be invertible" and "$A+D$ is invertible"?

Comment: No difference.  I've clarified the question.

Comment: Small note: it suffices to consider the case where $D$ has exactly one nonzero element.

Comment: This question is like a returning boomerang. No, there's no method to efficiently "update" the inverse or a factorisation of $A$ to get the inverse or a factorisation of $A+D$ unless $A$ and/or $D$ have some very special properties.

Comment: @GregMartin How can this give a faster method than recomputing the inverse or factors of $A+D$ from scratch?

Comment: Related : https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2977195/2987

Answer (score 5):

Since $(A+D)^{-1} = (I+ A^{-1} D)^{-1} A^{-1}$, and $A^{-1}$ is known, we just need to find out how to calculate $B ^{-1}$ where $B$ is the (known) matrix $1+A^{-1} D$.

Following Greg Martin's observation, consider first the case where the only nonzero entry of $D$ is in the upper left corner. In this case, all columns of $A^{-1} D$ are zero except the first one so $B$ has the form
$$ B = \begin{pmatrix} 
v_1 & 0 & 0 &\cdots & 0\\
v_2 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
v_3 & 0 & 1 & \cdots & 0 \\
\vdots & & & & \vdots \\
v_n & 0 & 0 &  \cdots & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix} 
v_1 & 0 & 0 &\cdots & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & \cdots & 0 \\
\vdots & & & & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & 0 &  \cdots & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 0 & 0 &\cdots & 0\\
v_2 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
v_3 & 0 & 1 & \cdots & 0 \\
\vdots & & & & \vdots \\
v_n & 0 & 0 &  \cdots & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$ 
Invertibility of $B$ is equivalent to the condition $v_1 \neq 0$. In this case both factors above are invertible. The inverse of the diagonal factor on the left is trivial to compute, and the inverse of the right factor happens to be
$$ \begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 0 & 0 &\cdots & 0\\
-v_2 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
-v_3 & 0 & 1 & \cdots & 0 \\
\vdots & & & & \vdots \\
-v_n & 0 & 0 &  \cdots & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$
so the inverse of $B$ is easy to recover. Namely:
$$B^{-1} = \begin{pmatrix} 
\frac{1}{v_1} & 0 & 0 &\cdots & 0\\
-\frac{v_2}{v_1} & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
-\frac{v_3}{v_1} & 0 & 1 & \cdots & 0 \\
\vdots & & & & \vdots \\
-\frac{v_n}{v_1} & 0 & 0 &  \cdots & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: The problem is that the case of $D$ having a single diagonal nonzero entry leads to a simple application of the Sherman-Morrison formula. However, this approach is generally useless if $D$ has the diagonal "denser" (e.g., if $D$ is full rank diagonal as given by the OP) and can lead to even more expensive method than just simply recomputing some sort of factorisation or the inverse of $A+D$.

Comment: @Pavel: I guess you're wanting low complexity in $n$? The question being stated as vaguely as it is, I'd say it's a bit pessimistic to assume the above procedure would be useless to the OP. It only needs repeating at most $n$ times, once for each each nonzero diagonal entry...

Comment: I got it from the question that $D$ has full rank (so there is no zero on the diagonal). Anyway, the procedure above costs $O(n^2)$, repeating $n$-times gives $O(n^3)$. Hence generally no gain.

Comment: @Pavel: I'm not saying I disagree with you, I'm just saying that, with no "computational complexity" tag, or similar, you might be reading more from the question than the asker intended.

Comment: Also, and I'm sure I'm being an ass by saying this, I think it's a bit rich that (what amounts to) the pretty trivial problem of inverting $I+X$ when $X$ is rank-1, is actually a named [result](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman%E2%80%93Morrison_formula) :)

Comment: Related : https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2977195/2987